# Interpreting a java card HelloWorld applet

Tags: java, javacard

Below, you see a java card program that returns "Hello Word" when it receive APDU Command =`8000000000` ([its source](https://umer555.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/java-card-hello-world-applet/))

```
package helloWorldPackage;

import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.Applet;
import javacard.framework.ISO7816;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;
import javacard.framework.Util;

public class HelloWorldApplet extends Applet 
{
    private static final byte[] helloWorld = {(byte)'H',(byte)'e',(byte)'l',(byte)'l',(byte)'o',(byte)' ',(byte)'W',(byte)'o',(byte)'r',(byte)'l',(byte)'d',};
    private static final byte HW_CLA = (byte)0x80;
    private static final byte HW_INS = (byte)0x00;

    public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) 
        {
        new HelloWorldApplet().register(bArray, (short) (bOffset + 1), bArray[bOffset]);
        }

    public void process(APDU apdu) 
        {
        if (selectingApplet()) 
            {
            return;
            }

        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        byte CLA = (byte) (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] & 0xFF);
        byte INS = (byte) (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS] & 0xFF);

        if (CLA != HW_CLA)
            {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_CLA_NOT_SUPPORTED);
            }

        switch ( INS ) 
            {
            case HW_INS:
                getHelloWorld( apdu );
                break;
            default:
                ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);
            }
        }

    private void getHelloWorld( APDU apdu)
        {
        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        short length = (short) helloWorld.length;
        Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(helloWorld, (short)0, buffer, (short)0, (short) length);
        apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short)0, length);
        }
}
```

I understand it, but I can't understand why the programmer used `&0XFF` in the lines :

```
        byte CLA = (byte) (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] & 0xFF);
        byte INS = (byte) (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS] & 0xFF);
```

Why he normally doesn't use the below line instead?

```
        byte CLA = (byte) (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA]);
        byte INS = (byte) (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS]);
```

And also in the line :

```
ew HelloWorldApplet().register(bArray, (short) (bOffset + 1), bArray[bOffset]);
```

What does he mean by the `+1` ?

Comment: Please ask 1 question per question, these are two.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Dear Marteen, please take a look at `getHelloWorld` method above. Is this right : "The author has defined a variable named `buffer` and initialized it with APDU buffer", right? So this user defined `buffer` is not the same APDU buffer? In the third line, he has copied the contents of his variable that named `helloWorld` to his another variable that named `buffer` (And not into the APDU buffer), right? So, why when he sends the APDU buffer in the last line(using `setOutgoingAndSend()`) the user receives contents of "helloWorld" variable?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes,  I know I'm wrong in something, but I don't know where it is! As far as I understand about the program, the programmer only changed his defined variable (the buffer) not the real APDU buffer that is used for `apdu.setOutgoingAndSend` method! :( so why the program works fine?! what is the point that I missed? Should I ask it as a new question in SO?

Comment: `apdu.getBuffer` **does** return the APDU buffer, what other buffer did you expect?

Comment: Assume this lines instead of the line above (I just changed the name of buffer to ask my question clear) : 
**1:** `byte[] temp = apdu.getBuffer();`
       **2:** `short length = (short) helloWorld.length;`
        **3:** `Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(helloWorld, (short)0, temp, (short)0, (short) length);`
        **4:** `apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short)0, length);`

--------- In **1** I copy the contents of _APDU buffer_ to my variable named _temp_. In **3** I copied the contents of my array  named _helloWord_ to my variable name _temp_. and finally In **4** I send the _APDU buffer_ to CAD.right?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes So I didn't changed the _APDU buffer_! I just made a copy of it and then modify the copy. Is this right? If so, why I receive the contents of "helloWorld" in the CAD?

Comment: You seriously need to upgrade your java skillset. You didn't make any copy of the APDU buffer.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes So what I did in **1** ? I copy some contents of APDU buffer to the temp?! Did I changed the APDU buffer anyway? where?

Comment: `apdu.getBuffer()` or the newer `APDU.getAPDUBuffer()` only retrieves *a reference to* the system held APDU buffer.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Oh! You saved my life :) thank you.No I understand what is going on :).  But why in the _JC 2.2.2 API Spec_ it is written that "It(`getbuffer` method) Returns the APDU buffer byte array." ? Does "**returning the APDU buffer byte array**" equal with "**returning the contents of APDU buffer byte array**"? Or it is must read as "**returning a reference of APDU buffer byte array**"? Is it my weakness in English language, or it is written badly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70657/discussion-between-maarten-bodewes-and-am1r).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although we cannot see intent of an author, the line:

```
    byte CLA = (byte) (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] & 0xFF);
```

is 100% equivalent to:

```
    byte CLA = buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA];
```

Java does often use integers as result of operations, and because Java Card usually does not support `int` values, it is often needed to cast to `byte` or `short`. I can only guess that the `& 0xFF` and cast are present because of an over-enthusiastic attempt to get rid of intermediate `int` values. It could also be a bad attempt to get Java to support unsigned bytes.

---

The `register` method expects the instance AID. That AID is within the user parameters given during the Global Platform `INSTALL for INSTALL`, but it is preceded by a byte containing the length of the AID (between 5 and 15, inclusive). So the `+ 1` is to skip that length byte - which is in turn present at the last argument of the `register` method: `bArray[bOffset]`.

Comment: Dear Maarten, I checked some other applets. They are used the same `&` character in their applets in cases like the case in the question. please take a look here : http://www.cs.ru.nl/E.Poll/hw/samples/CryptoApplet.java (search for & character in the code.) and also take a look here : http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076450/client-side-java/how-to-write-a-java-card-applet--a-developer-s-guide.html (bottom of the page). Are you sure they used this character unduly?

Comment: They did in the code of the question. In the first sample you linked to there is a conversion from *signed* byte to *signed* short, where the byte contents are treated as a positive value. So in that case the `& 0xFF` makes sense. It basically converts the sign bit into a bit that is part of the positive value, and resets the higher bits (8..16). In above the result is stored into a signed byte again, which of course doesn't make sense, bit 7 will be the sign bit again - so you're back to the point where it all started.

Comment: In the second link I see strange conversions happening, I won't go into them if you don't mind. Read the Java lang spec and see it as a puzzle. If you don't understand these conversions you *are* going to make mistakes in any Applet you develop (!).

Comment: @Am1r You're welcome. The picture still needs some work, I am just starting to learn the app on my tablet :)